# I am unable to call a JSP using RequestDispatcher forward

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have this servlet calling this JSP

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<%

 %>
</body>
</html>
```

But dont know why this is giving me this error

> Sep 10, 2011 4:15:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Test threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.jsp.Mine_jsp._jspInit(Mine_jsp.java:22)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
>     at Test.doGet(Test.java:31)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Please post the servlet code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException 
>   at org.apache.jsp.Mine_jsp._jspInit(Mine_jsp.java:22)

A NPE on `_jspInit()` is typical whenever the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp is littered with servletcontainer-specific libraries such as `jsp-api.jar`, `j2ee.jar`, etcetera. This is a major mistake, those libraries belong in the servletcontainer side. Cleanup your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder to remove them all. If you put them there to overcome compilation errors, you should have solved it differently. See also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)